# Random number generator and pattern matching - OCaml

Tags: ocaml

In order to learn about pattern matching, I'm currently trying to generate a number from 1 to 3 in Ocaml and write it to stdout.

This is what I wrote so far (function with empty argument):

```
let random_compchoice () = match Random.int 3 with
    | 1 -> "1"
    | 2 -> "2"
    | 3 -> "3"
    | _ -> "Error"
;;

Printf.printf "The option is %s\n" random_compchoice;;
```

However this triggers:

```
**Error**: This expression has type unit -> string
       but an expression was expected of type string
```

But, if I do this:

```
let random_compchoice = match Random.int 3 with
    | 1 -> "1"
    | 2 -> "2"
    | 3 -> "3"
    | _ -> "Error"
;;

Printf.printf "The option is %s\n" random_compchoice;;
```

It compiles but always defaults to:

```
The option is Error
```

Any ideas of what I am missing there? Thanks in advance.
(Also not sure that it is possible to start with 1 as first 'case' and not 0).

Comment: To answer your last question, you can have any patterns you want. They don't really "start" anywhere. OCaml will warn if the patterns don't cover every possible case. On the other hand `Random.int 3` returns 0, 1, or 2.

Comment: ... and we would need refinement type to make the match exhaustive, so you'll always need that catch-all until then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your first example, you need to actually call the function with the `unit` argument,

```
Printf.printf "The option is %s\n" @@ random_compchoice ();;
```

As to why the second sample always fails, there are two reasons. Why it *always* fails is because you haven't initialized the Random number generator with (at least),

```
Random.self_init ()
```

If you don't do this you'll get the same stream of random numbers on each execution in this case, 0. Additionally, [the random number generator of integers is from 0 (inclusive) ... n (exclusive)](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Random.html). You can just add one to the generated random number,

```
... = match 1 + Random.int 3 with ...
```